# Access Windows admin share from Android?

Tags: networking, windows, file-sharing, cifs

I have tested several Android apps and none of them seem to be able to do what I want.

How do I access admin shares such as `\\host\c$` from Android?

Note that admin share access is enabled on the host and I can in fact access it from another Windows machine. Last time I checked it even works from Debian Linux. Now, Android either has some deeply rooted issues with this or it lacks the proper tools/apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). It can access user shared folders + administrative shares.

Comment: This app really worked! I tried many different cifs and smb "clients", and also the ASTRO file manager. But I couldn't do it with any of them. ASTRO has a separate CIFS/SMB component you download, but it's not been maintained for some time now and apparently ASTRO can now support CIFS/SMB shares directly within the main app. Unfortunately it only shows user shared folders. No administrative shares, and no way to *add* a custom network location like with ES File Explorer. ASTRO only allows you to browse user shared folders.

Comment: Worth noting is that it doesn't use UNC notation like `\\host\something` instead you have to type `host\something` like that. It has some problems with adding or connecting to admin shares, like for instance I added `host\c$` and it was OK, and I could tap to open. But for `host\l$` on the same machine it kept saying **error, cannot find the server** and it won't add it when I tap OK button. When I go back to "server" field and type it in again, and then tap OK, it works then. Looks like a bug.

Comment: False alarm! I have found the culprit. It's not a bug. Apparently when I type in the dollar character $ in any text input field, my Android introduces whitespace. So instead of `host\c$` I will get `host\c $` with an extra space between drive letter and dollar character. So I have to go back and remove that whitespace. Then it works. This is on a Galaxy S4 Plus. Other phones may not be affected.